# C# Custom ListView

Tags: c#, listview

Does anyone have any info on creating/drawing a customised ListView object?

Currently Im working on a project that requires a customised look and feel within the application. I am using a standard (Windows.Forms) ListView which is not in the same style as the rest of the GUI. We are NOT using a toolbox for custom controls, all controlls are 'skinned' inhouse as it were by overriding hte OnPaint() method for each control.

What Im looking for is:
- Information about how to handle drawing of the Scroll Bar.
- How to use customised drawing routines to handle the column headers.
- How to still handle the data shown and draw that correctly.

Any and all help would be greatly received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell you will need to actually make some Win32 calls using `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` to actually change the paint behavior of the control. [Here is one](https://web.archive.org/web/20061221082010/http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.windowsforms/topic34342.aspx) article I found.  You are going to have to do a bit more digging.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass `ListBox`.  In the ctor, set the draw mode to `OwnerDrawVariable` and override `OnDrawItem` and `OnMeasureItem`.  I like to have a special Item class which allows the user to specify any custom drawing for that item as well as an `object` which will be the data.