# Reducing lag when rendering multiple pictureboxes on form

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, picturebox

I am developing a simple level editor in C# that uses tiles that are of size 16x16. The default level size is 256x256 which would need 16 tiles on each row (16 rows). This would mean for the default level size, a total of 256 tiles are needed. The tiles are rendered in a picturebox control onto a panel. As you can probably guess, after about 100+ tiles on a mid-spec laptop, the application encounters lag even while moving the mouse.

The application is a WinForms application.

I am wondering how I can fix this.

My PC Specs:

- Windows 7 64bit
- 2.5-3GHz Intel i5 CPU
- Intel HD 4000 GPU (64Mb dedicated video memory - probably the problem)
- 6GB DDR3 1600MHz Memory (RAM)
- Running off a 750GB HDD

What I have tried:

- Enabling double buffering for both the panel and the form the pictureboxes are being rendered on.
- Making a custom Control that draws images in a simple way.

Both of these methods have led to the same lack of success and visual lag.

I have read many other answers and the solutions above seem to be the only ones out there despite the fact that they were of no avail to me.

Comment: A WinForms app I suppose?

Comment: Yes @Steve - I shall specify now in the OP.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going about this the wrong way if you are trying to display 256+ controls at the same time...

Comment: @Okuma.Scott how would you go about it?

Comment: Find a way to combine the display of your tiles in a single control. [This might point you in the right direction...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/862021/2596334).

Comment: @Okuma.Scott thanks for that! I had even done that to generate a preview of the level already - my stupid head...

Comment: Do you want to post that as an answer so I can accept it :) @Okuma.Scott

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of trying to display each tile as it's own control, consolidate your objects into one control.

There is already a **[great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/862021/2596334)** here on stack that describes how it's done.