# WPF DataGrid only calculate visible rows

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I remeber reading an article a couple months back about a feature or DataGrid or an extended version of DataGrid that only wires up the notifications, bindings, etc. on the rows visible to the user and a few not visible to provide quick display when showing.

I cannot find this article and my Googling is not coming up with anything.

Does anyone know what this feature is and what it is called?

The reason I am wanting to do this is because I am displaying a DataGrid with a large number of rows (1000+).  The rows are defined such that two of the cells display a combo box of possible values.  Without these combo boxes the data grid loads (executes a SQL script and converts to a DataTable bound to the DataGrid) and displays almost instantly.  When I add the combo boxes the loading takes about 10-15 seconds.  I think the article addressed this and said the performance would be better as the DataGrid is only creating the combo boxes necessary to the immediate view and not all 1000+ rows.

I am open to other suggestions on how to avoid the long wait times when adding the combo boxes to the DataGrid (requirements state the these two cells are combo boxes so removing is not an option).

Comment: that is called paging

Comment: You might be thinking of [RowVirtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...

Comment: You are looking for the attached Properties VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing and VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode. If that doesn't help enough and/or causes other issues you don't like (there are a few), you may also want to look into DataVirtualization http://www.zagstudio.com/blog/378#.VAnmAfldWQA

Comment: @Okuma Scott I can't believe I never seen that property when searching for solutions to this myself. All the answers I saw led to the VirtualizingStackPanel. Okuma's comment is a better answer I think for the UI Virtualization. Check out the link above for Data Virtaulization.

Comment: @Okuma.Scott If you would add your comment as an answer I will mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you're thinking of the [RowVirtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.enablerowvirtualization%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) property?

`... When the EnableRowVirtualization property is set to true, the DataGrid does not instantiate a DataGridRow object for each data item in the bound data source. Instead, the DataGrid creates DataGridRow objects only when they are needed ...`

In other words this will improve performance by only loading into memory the rows which are being displayed. There is a limit to the number of controls a typical application can display before things start getting very sluggish. **Virtualizing** controls is the answer to this problem.

For example, refer to the answer to this question: [Upper (reasonable) limit to number of user control instances](https://stackoverflow.com/a/862021/2596334). Even though this applies to UserControls specifically, the same concept applies to all controls.