# How many controls can I create and show in a Windows Forms form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm developing a C# Windows Forms application. I know that too many controls makes a terrible user experience, and I would keep the number of controls visible at the same time small (for example, as suggested in *[Upper (reasonable) limit to number of user control instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851553/upper-reasonable-limit-to-number-of-user-control-instances)*), but some of controls may be hidden (i.e. using tabs or layers).

Is there an absolute maximum number of controls I can show on a form, and if there is one, what is it?

Comment: Any number that you like, if you would generate them dynamically.

Comment: Hi, this isnt a very clear question...or it is just oddly simple. What do you mean by fit on a form? The simple answer is it depends on how big your form is and how big the controls are? That's assuming you don't overlap...but is that what you are talking about? Surely that what be a geometry problem not a programming one

Comment: Exactly that many your app's users can handle without going crazy.

Comment: If you are in the situation when you need to ask this question, that means you're doing something wrong.

Comment: If you have to ask that, you're doing something wrong. Anyway there's no hard limit. Why do you want to know this? See also [Upper (reasonable) limit to number of user control instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851553/upper-reasonable-limit-to-number-of-user-control-instances) for example. What have you tried?

Comment: If you're asking this out of curiousity, write some code to create controls in a loop and see when you run out of memory. If you're asking because you're worried that you may exceed the limit in a piece of software you're developing, you need to redesign your UI / UX.

Comment: I would imagine there is probably a limit beyond which not only is it impossible to manage code wise, but that either it refuses or performance is effected.  having tabs and controls that swap in/out depending on other values, you can probably have a heck of a lot, but it does suggest there is an issue with why

Comment: @Alexei your edit really improves the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, there is a limit, though not hard coded and configurable - and its default value is 10,000 ([why?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070718-00/?p=25963)).

Each control is creating a [user-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sysinfo/user-objects) in the operating system, and the default maximum number of active user-objects per process in Windows is 10,000 - so once you will try to add the 10,001 control to the form you should get an exception of type [System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.win32exception?view=netframework-4.7.2) with the message:

> Error creating window handle.

Of course, no user would want to see a form with 10,000 controls, so unless you have a leak somewhere, this should never happen. (And of course, the only reason I know about it is just because I've had this leak in the past - I've had user controls listening to events from a static class and didn't unhook them in the `Dispose` method, so even after they where cleared from the screen, they were still alive...)

When you get this exception, look at the Processes tab of Task manager.
Click the *View* menu, inside click *Select Columns*, mark the checkbox of *USER Objects* (it's not visible by default; that fact probably cost me a couple of hours when attempting to understand my leak) - and then sort by that column. If you see your application at the top, with 10,000 user objects - then you know your application have reached the maximum number of controls - which means you have a leak you need to fix.

Please note that even if you remove the controls from the form, if they have some other reference they will not get disposed and you will, eventually, get this error if your application is running enough time.

If anyone is interested, here is the code I've used to re-create the error (including designer code)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace UserObjectsLeak
{
    public partial class FrmUserObjectsLeak : Form
    {
        // This is used to keep references of the labels being added dynamically.
        static readonly List<Label> Labels = new List<Label>();

        public FrmUserObjectsLeak()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 11000; i++)
            {
                var label = new Label()
                {
                    Text = i.ToString(),
                    Width = 50
                };
                Labels.Add(label);
                try
                {
                    panel1.Controls.Add(label);
                }
                catch (System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception ex)
                {
                    lblException.Text = ex.ToString();
                    return;
                }

                lblControlsCount.Text = (i).ToString();

                // Quick and dirty just to show the progress...
                Application.DoEvents();

                if (i % 500 == 0)
                {
                    // Remove all labels from the panel,
                    // keep only the reference in the list.
                    panel1.Controls.Clear();
                }
            }
        }

        private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            panel1.Controls.Clear();
            Labels.Clear();
            lblControlsCount.Text = "";
            lblException.Text = "";
        }

        #region Designer code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.btnStart = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.lblControlsCount = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.btnClear = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel();
            this.lblException = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // label1
            // 
            this.label1.AutoSize = true;
            this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 17);
            this.label1.Name = "label1";
            this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(191, 13);
            this.label1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.label1.Text = "Click the button to start adding controls";
            // 
            // label2
            // 
            this.label2.AutoSize = true;
            this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 95);
            this.label2.Name = "label2";
            this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(77, 13);
            this.label2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.label2.Text = "controls count:";
            // 
            // btnStart
            // 
            this.btnStart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 49);
            this.btnStart.Name = "btnStart";
            this.btnStart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnStart.TabIndex = 2;
            this.btnStart.Text = "Start";
            this.btnStart.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnStart.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnStart_Click);
            // 
            // lblControlsCount
            // 
            this.lblControlsCount.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblControlsCount.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(95, 95);
            this.lblControlsCount.Name = "lblControlsCount";
            this.lblControlsCount.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
            this.lblControlsCount.TabIndex = 3;
            // 
            // btnClear
            // 
            this.btnClear.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(98, 49);
            this.btnClear.Name = "btnClear";
            this.btnClear.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.btnClear.TabIndex = 5;
            this.btnClear.Text = "Clear";
            this.btnClear.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnClear.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClear_Click);
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.FlowDirection = System.Windows.Forms.FlowDirection.TopDown;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(226, 17);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 148);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 6;
            // 
            // lblException
            // 
            this.lblException.AutoSize = true;
            this.lblException.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(15, 179);
            this.lblException.Name = "lblException";
            this.lblException.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 13);
            this.lblException.TabIndex = 7;
            // 
            // frmUserObjectsLeak
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(452, 308);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblException);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnClear);
            this.Controls.Add(this.lblControlsCount);
            this.Controls.Add(this.btnStart);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
            this.Name = "FrmUserObjectsLeak";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "User Objects Leak Demo";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.PerformLayout();

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnStart;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblControlsCount;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClear;
        private System.Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label lblException;

        #endregion Designer code
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice to see a positive responsive. People are going way too meta on this. The question is a reasonable one. If someone is not familiar with dynamically creating components it may be difficult for them to prove this quickly. They may be hoping to build a large form with many components but not know whether they will hit a hard limit before they are done.

Comment: @Creyke It took me about two days to find what the problem was, and another half a day to figure out why it happened and how to fix it. If I can save another programmer that time, then this answer is worth the time I've invested in it, and so is the question.

Comment: What is the error message? (in case it isn't obvious, quoting the message here will help other users to find the answer easier.)

Comment: @user202729 I wish I would remember it. This happened about 3 years ago... I'll try to re-create this situation on my computer just to test.

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for your comment. I've recreated the error and updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is no limit if it is added dynamically from the form constructor, for experimenting, I added 100 thousand labels and 10 thousand panels with color although it took more than 15 minutes to display (pc: 8 ram, SixCore 3.50 GHz cpu) after that the form was shown there are no performance problems (it consumed 30mb of ram memory) neither the dragging of the form was affected.

However, as the previous comment says (#Zohard Peled), if the form has already been displayed, only 10,000 controls can be added.