# Dynamically adding thousands of text box on winform caused no response

Tags: c#, excel, winforms

Now I am using refedit control in c# to select cells in Excel.
Then for each cell, I want to generate two text boxes and a label for it on the winform.
When it has 40 or 50 cells, it works well. But when there are thousands of cells (e.g. A1:ESI1 in excel), it is always stuck and no responses with below error message.

> The application is in break mode.
>
> Managed Debugging Assistant 'ContextSwitchDeadlock' : 'The CLR has been unable to transition from COM context 0xd6b9e10 to COM context 0xd6b9d58 for 60 seconds. The thread that owns the destination context/apartment is most likely either doing a non pumping wait or processing a very long running operation without pumping Windows messages. This situation generally has a negative performance impact and may even lead to the application becoming non responsive or memory usage accumulating continually over time. To avoid this problem, all single threaded apartment (STA) threads should use pumping wait primitives (such as CoWaitForMultipleHandles) and routinely pump messages during long running operations.'

And the add_text_box code is like

```
// Above are some codes to detect the selected cells, 
// then store the cell name in a list NamesVariablesChosen          
// label_l, label_n and label_u are three static elements defined above

int heightStep = 23 + 23;
tabPage1.SuspendLayout();
for (int i = 0; i <= NamesVariablesChosen.Length - 1; i++)
{
      System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
      System.Windows.Forms.TextBox textBox_2 = new System.Windows.Forms.TextBox();
      System.Windows.Forms.Label label_ = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();

      label_.Size = label_n.Size;
      label_.Location = new Point(label_n.Location.X, label_n.Location.Y + heightStep);
      label_.Text = NamesVariablesChosen[i];
      label_.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;

      textBox_1.Size = label_l.Size;
      textBox_1.Location = new Point(label_l.Location.X, label_l.Location.Y + heightStep);
      textBox_1.Text = ""; 

      textBox_2.Size = label_u.Size;
      textBox_2.Location = new Point(label_u.Location.X, label_u.Location.Y + heightStep);
      textBox_2.Text = ""; 


      heightStep += 46;

      tabPage1.Controls.Add(textBox_1);
      tabPage1.Controls.Add(textBox_2);
      tabPage1.Controls.Add(label_);
}

tabPage1.ResumeLayout(false);
tabPage1.PerformLayout();
tabPage1.Update();
```

When I select 3000 cells in Excel, it cannot generate 3000 corresponding text boxes and labels. I was wondering what is the problem here, and how I can solve it.

Comment: Use a DataGridView.

Comment: You likely already read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944471/how-many-controls-can-i-create-and-show-in-a-windows-forms-form, just adding for people who may want to answer so they avoid duplication.

Comment: I have to ask this... why not millions?

Comment: You'll need to provide a good [mcve] to get any sort of good help on this question. In the meantime: the exception is a debugger helper that occurs any time the main UI thread is blocked for an extended period of time. 3000 text boxes is a very large number of controls, which is sure to slow things down. You should look into virtualizing the UI, so that you only populate the UI with controls that the user can interact with at any given time (surely you don't expect a user to see 3000 text boxes at once).