# Program crashes sporadically at Controls.Add(Control c) method

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, task

I have built a nested user control (framework 4.8) that can hold many child user controls. All squares are part of one user control, that is placed on the "Bord" which is a `FlowLayouPanel`:

[image]

The program is crashing (sporadically) when the control is populated with too much elements. So I added a paging function to paint on a subset of controls.

My experience is, that when I have small projects with not so much child controls inside, it is working perfectly. When I have big projects - with about 2000 single controls, the program starts and I can browse, but the program sporadically crashes. I can produce a crash with one of the following actions:

- Fast browsing forward or back
- Painting pages with many controls

My program crashes in the following methods at Controls.Add (where _epicpanel is the container E that holds many single controls, painted in brown color):

```
public async Task AddEpicPanel(EpicPanel _epicpanel)
{
    EpicPanels.Add(_epicpanel);
    SuperPanelBoard.Controls.Add(_epicpanel); // <<<CRASH
        
    _epicpanel.Parent = SuperPanelBoard;
    _epicpanel.Refresh();
}
```

I tried to paint the controls async but it did not help. I do not receive any detailed exceptions in Visual Studio. It says "Failed to create window handle". I do not know what I can do, async methods are not enough? I very much appreciate any ideas!

Comment: I'd say, get a trial for dotMemory and/or dotTrace from jetBrains. Their tooling has helped me more than once. In your case, it might be a memory issue, but without more data, that's a somewhat wild guess.

Comment: I can't be sure but a pretty good guess would be that [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52944934/3094533) can help you.

Comment: Windows handles (aka controls) are subjected to a quota, a process is not allowed to create more than 10,000 of them.  This is a counter-measure against running out of handle storage, the desktop heap that stores window and drawing object handles for all processes can't store more than 65535 objects.  You can see this with Task Manager, details tab, add the "User objects" column.  Consider to favor painting with the Graphics class over controls, also helps a lot with program responsiveness.

Comment: Fwiw, a traditional bug in a Winforms program is to use Controls.Clear() or Controls.Remove() instead of Controls.Dispose().  The controls that are removed this way live forever, waiting to be moved back to a visible parent.

Comment: BINGO! Thank you very much guys, this was the problem. I created 10.000 user objects. I use .Dispose() but not correctly it seems :)  Now I know which way to go

Comment: In that case, I'm closing as a duplucate.

Comment: Additional info:
To avoid a crash, I now check the user objects during execution. Over a threshold of 9000 I tell the user that data is not shown completely and that paging was reduced to smaller pages. Applying a more stringent filter would also help.
GetGuiResourcesUserCount()

I do this with PINVOKE and GetGuiResourcesUserCount()